# How to force child elements to expand the parent element?

Tags: css

I make a drop-down menu with a lot of items (I don't know exactly how many).

I expect the child `<ul>` to expand to `max-width` when it has enough items, but actually it expands to parent `<div>`'s `width` only, no more.

Why?

*Upd*: I want to break long lines, not to shrink them by `flex`.

*Upd 2*: I want to the child `<ul>` to be not smaller than the parent `<div>`.

```css
div {
  background: aquamarine;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

ul {
  background: blue;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

li {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

a {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>A</a>
      <a>B</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>A</a>
      <a>B</a>
      <a>C</a>
      <a>D</a>
      <a>E</a>
      <a>F</a>
      <a>G</a>
      <a>H</a>
      <a>I</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can move the relative positioning up to a parent element that is wide enough to handle the 500px:

```css
div.wide-load {
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

div.direct-parent {
  background: aquamarine;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}

ul {
  background: blue;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

li {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

a {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wide-load">
  <div class="direct-parent">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>A</a>
        <a>B</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>A</a>
        <a>B</a>
        <a>C</a>
        <a>D</a>
        <a>E</a>
        <a>F</a>
        <a>G</a>
        <a>H</a>
        <a>I</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you are unable to do this, then your only other option is to make the li's `white-space:nowrap` - but this will not respect your max-width:

```css
div.direct-parent {
  background: aquamarine;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}

ul {
  background: blue;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

li {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

a {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="direct-parent">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>A</a>
      <a>B</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>A</a>
      <a>B</a>
      <a>C</a>
      <a>D</a>
      <a>E</a>
      <a>F</a>
      <a>G</a>
      <a>H</a>
      <a>I</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your 1'st option is pretty good for me; if nobody gives a better solution without additional `div`, I will use it. Thanks.

Comment: @Sam, you don't need the extra div - it's just showing you a parent element that is wide enough for the 500px - it could be that you go up to the body if you wanted - https://jsfiddle.net/25p0871f/ (with any number of parent divs: https://jsfiddle.net/25p0871f/1/)

Comment: It's almost perfect; but what if I want the child `<ul>` to be not smaller than the parent `<div>`?

Comment: put a min-width of 200px on that?

Comment: Then you are going to need js as you have now removed the ul from the flow of the parent div - but if it is smaller than the width of the document then you must have put a width on it so you should know the width

Answer (score 1):

```
li {
    background: yellow none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: flex;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

You can use

```
display: flex;
```

Comment: Flex works well, but I want to break long lines, not to shrink them.

Answer (score 0):

It's the principle of `max-width`. You force an item to never be larger than the specified unit, but this doesn't automatically mean that your element will ever reach that length. In this case, your absolutely positioned `<ul>` is still restricted to it's initial parent, which forces it to be a maximum of `200px` long.

Comment: That depends, do you wish for your first `<ul>` to honor the initial 200px width?

Comment: yes, I do. The `<ul>` must be not smaller than the parent `div`.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: An additional option not mentioned yet:

### Use intrinsic sizing for the width:

```
ul {
  ...
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 500px;
  ...
}
```

From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#width-height-keywords):

> **max-content** If specified for the inline axis, use the max-content inline size; otherwise compute to auto.

**NB:** you can use `max-width: 500px` in conjunction with the width property to ensure that the content width never exceeds 500px (`max-width` will override `width`).

```css
div {
  background: aquamarine;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

ul {
  background: blue;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: -webkit-max-content;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

li {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

a {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>A</a>
      <a>B</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>A</a>
      <a>B</a>
      <a>C</a>
      <a>D</a>
      <a>E</a>
      <a>F</a>
      <a>G</a>
      <a>H</a>
      <a>I</a>
      <a>A</a>
      <a>B</a>
      <a>C</a>
      <a>D</a>
      <a>E</a>
      <a>F</a>
      <a>G</a>
      <a>H</a>
      <a>I</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width) is also pretty good (Except for IE/Edge)

Comment: Works great, but I would prefer a solution with IE support.

Answer (score -1):

You want something like this? I changed the `width: 200px` of `div` to `max-width:500px` and removed the `max-width:500px` in `ul`

```css
div {
  background: aquamarine;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 500px;
}

ul {
  background: blue;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

li {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

a {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>A</a>
      <a>B</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>A</a>
      <a>B</a>
      <a>C</a>
      <a>D</a>
      <a>E</a>
      <a>F</a>
      <a>G</a>
      <a>H</a>
      <a>I</a>
      <a>E</a>
      <a>F</a>
      <a>G</a>
      <a>H</a>
      <a>I</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I want `div` to still 200px, and `ul` expand to 500px.